# Windows Azure project not listed in Eclipse

Tags: java, azure

im following the microsoft azure documentaion and i installed azure toolkit for eclipse but Windows Azure project is not listed in eclipse projects..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-creating-a-hello-world-application

Comment: Please include the documentation you are following. Hence we know where you could gone wrong.

Comment: Please post more details about what you did when you were following the offical sample tutorial, which include your eclipse version, eclipse logs, some necessary screenshots of your eclipse. Otherwise, I don't know how to help.